# Why is this form evaluating to true?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
<form name="companyProfileForm" autocomplete="false" novalidate ng-submit="OnSaveCompanyProfile(companyProfileForm.$valid)" ng-controller="companyProfileDataEntryController">
    <section ng-hide="!IsCompanyKnown();" class="row">
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns">
            <!--Industry-->
            <section class="row">
                <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : (companyProfileForm.Industry.$invalid && submitted) }">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Industry">*Industry</label>

                        <select name="Industry"
                                ng-model="CompanyProfileModel.IndustryId"
                                ng-options="item.Id as item.Description for item in IndustryList"
                                required>
                            <option value=null>-- select an industry --</option>
                        </select>

                        <span class="help-block" ng-show="companyProfileForm.Industry.$invalid && submitted">Please select a value.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </section>
    <button></button>
</form>
```

No matter what I do this form will evaluate to true. I want it to throw an error that Industry is required. Upon submit it goes to a function that prints to the console the parameter. It prints true every time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the AngularJS ng-required directive, not required. Change the select element required to ng-required="true":

```
<select name="Industry" ng-model="CompanyProfileModel.IndustryId" ng-options="item.Id as item.Description for item in IndustryList" ng-required="true">
  <option value=null>-- select an industry --</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 'required' on a form element **will** work in angular so long as your **form** element has an ng-submit="action()" and a button EXACTLY as follows inside the form:

```
<button type='submit' ng-click='submit()'>SomeText</button>
```